# Random sample from a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,1,2,3,3)
date<-c("23-01-08","01-11-07","30-11-07","17-12-07","12-12-08")
df<-data.frame(id,date)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")

id     date      date2
1   23-01-08 2008-01-23
1   01-11-07 2007-11-01
2   30-11-07 2007-11-30
3   17-12-07 2007-12-17
3   12-12-08 2008-12-12
```

Now I want to extract a random sample of ids and not the rows. In fact I am looking for a way to randomly pick two of the ids and extract all records  related to them. For instance if it randomly pick ids 2 and 3 the output data frame should look like:

```
id     date      date2
2   30-11-07 2007-11-30
3   17-12-07 2007-12-17
3   12-12-08 2008-12-12
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can randomly pick two IDs using `sample()`

```
chosen <- sample(unique(df$id), 2)
```

and then extract those records

```
subset(df, id %in% chosen)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(id %in% sample(unique(id),2))
#  id     date      date2
#1  2 30-11-07 2007-11-30
#2  3 17-12-07 2007-12-17
#3  3 12-12-08 2008-12-12
```

Or

```
df %>%
     select(id) %>%
     unique() %>%
     sample_n(2) %>%
     semi_join(df, .)
#  id     date      date2
#1  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23
#2  1 01-11-07 2007-11-01
#3  2 30-11-07 2007-11-30
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sample` function.

```
set.seed(2)
df[match(sample(unique(df$id),2),df$id),]
```

`sample()` function will generate random indexes and then you can match them back to your `df` data frame rows and get the rest of the data.
For more information check `?sample`

Comment: That doesn't give the intended result - you always get 5 rows returned.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

First you have to generate the sample indexes:

```
s_ids=sample(unique(df$id),2)
```

now that you have that you select the proper records in your df

```
new_df=df$[df$id %in% s_ids,]
```

Comment: This won't work if you have duplicate id values. I.e., in the current data, you might pick `1` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
a <- sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT id FROM df  ORDER BY RANDOM(*) LIMIT 2")
sqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE id IN a")
```

Ouput:

```
  id     date      date2
1  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23
2  1 01-11-07 2007-11-01
3  3 17-12-07 2007-12-17
4  3 12-12-08 2008-12-12
```