# Rstudio extract sub database

Tags: r

I have a small question regarding Rstudo : is it possible to subset a large database based on a criteria. I have a large dataset of companies with several observations (monthly) per company. Since the data base is very large, I would like to reduce it by only taking a sample of firms (10% of the total number of firms which is not the same as 10% of the total observations to be clear). Is it possible to do so ?

For example in the small example below, can I randomly draw 33% of the firms (2 firms) for all the year they appear ?

```
year_results<-data.frame(Year=c(2006,2006,2006,2007,2007,2007,2008,2008,2008,2008),
Firm=c("100D","102D","106D","100D","102D","103D","104D","102D","104D","105E"),
Sales=c(100,120,110,120,105,105,100,135,125,110))
```

A possible result would be the following data subset:

```
year_results2<-data.frame(Year=c(2006,2006,2007,2007,2008),
Firm=c("100D","102D","100D","102D","102D"),
Sales=c(100,120,120,105,135))
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Look at `subset()` or `dplyr::filter()`.

Comment: @Phil thank you, I know those functions, I really like dplyr,and there is this discussion in the forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018644/random-sample-from-a-data-frame-in-r which answered part of the question but my question is rather how do I take a given share of the ids and not an exact number and that is still unclear to me

Comment: Oh, sorry for misreading. `dplyr::slice_sample()` will do that for you. E.g. `dplyr::slice_sample(mtcars, prop = 0.33)`.

Comment: @Phil thank you but that is not really what I am looking for : here I would get 33% of the database, i.e. I get only 3 observations. What I would like is 33% of the firms in the example above to appear in my sample (see yzar_results2 above). Is there a refinement from sample to do this ?